# How to multi thread my code to process several files at the same time, by the same function?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using the below routine to process a group of videos from a directory:

```
AllVideos = new List<MyVideo>();

for (int i = 0; i < AllVideosFileNames.Length; i++)
{
    MyVideo CurrentVid = new MyVideo(AllVideosFileNames[i], false); // constructor (loads the video to the system) 
    CurrentVid.PopulateAllFrames(); // Method that takes forever
    CurrentVid.PopluateTestFrames(); // Method that takes less than forever
    CurrentVid.NormalizeTestFrames(); // Method that takes some time
    AllVideos.Add(CurrentVid); // Add finished object to my results container
}
```

I would like to process several videos at the same time, in parallel, and save time. I tried doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllVideosFileNames.Length; i++)
{
    Thread TempThread = new Thread(() => 
    {
        MyVideo CurrentVid = new MyVideo(AllVideosFileNames[i], false);
        CurrentVid.PopulateAllFrames();
        CurrentVid.PopluateTestFrames();
        CurrentVid.NormalizeTestFrames();
        AllVideos.Add(CurrentVid);
    });
    TempThread.Start();
}
```

However, this executes so fast and does literally nothing. By nothing I mean when I step through the code, `AllVideos` is empty when the loop finishes executing.

Any ideas for a better design? or a fix? Please and thanks.

Comment: Try using/learning TPL which is more better and you've controll over your tasks.[See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you just start one thread for each piece of work, the parent thread will just continue. You have to wait for them to finish. I'd prefer instead to create a Task for each one (using `Task.Run`), then do a `Task.Wait` on the created tasks after they've been created. Then they will run in parallel to completion

Comment: how long does it in the normal loop for 1 iteration? It seems that your threads are sill running when the loop finishes. What about `AllVideos``? where does it come from? you might have race condition problems if it is not a local variable. consider locking

Comment: you could use a `Parallel.Foreach()` method. This will wait automatically until the last thread is finished

Comment: @Baldrick I tried to use that and I read about `Task.WaitAll` which takes _all_ the tasks created as parameters. But what if I don't know the count of files? Hence the count of tasks created (in order to hard code them as parameters)

Comment: @KyleKhalaf If you don't know how many you'd just collect them in a list.

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` takes an array of tasks. Just add each one to an `List<Task>` as you create them, then do `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray())`. The example here shows exactly that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @MongZhu it takes around 2 to 3 mins for each file (in linear processing). Parallel.Foreach() sounds like a fix. But sorry I assume this is a _local variable_ and there won't be a race condition problem correct? -> https://s9.postimg.org/v5awzgya7/Capture.png

Comment: the order might be a bit scrambled but otherwise it looks fine

Comment: Awesome thanks guys! I will try all and pick the best answer for documentation. @MongZhu

Comment: CC: @Baldrick Thanks

Comment: CC: @juharr Thanks

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I would also like to tell you that `Thread` should preferably not be used anymore as `async`, `await` and TPL are designed to replace `Thread` and `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Will this actually save any time?  Can your disk drive actually process multiple files at the same time?  It seems like the disk will be the bottleneck, far more than the processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe look into TPL and/or PLINQ. Do you know about `.AsParallel()`?

How about:

```
AllVideos = AllVideosFileNames
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(fileName => GetVideo(filename))
    .ToList();
```

Where `GetVideo(filename)` is defined as followed:

```
private MyVideo GetVideo(string filename)
{
    MyVideo currentVid = new MyVideo(filename, false);
    currentVid.PopulateAllFrames();
    currentVid.PopluateTestFrames();
    currentVid.NormalizeTestFrames();
    return currentVid;
}
```

See [Introduction to PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: `AllVideosFileNames[i]` should be `filename`

Comment: @MatiasCicero Thanks for catching that! It is now fixed.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Is there a way to know when does processing for all files finish? (No I do not know about `AsParallel` but it looks awesome)

Comment: @KyleKhalaf Any code that you put after the above statements will be executed after all filenames have been processed. `ToList()` takes care of that.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx). It will wait until the last thread is finished its execution before proceeding:

```
Parallel.ForEach(AllVideosFileNames, item =>
{
    MyVideo CurrentVid = new MyVideo(item, false);
    CurrentVid.PopulateAllFrames();
    CurrentVid.PopluateTestFrames();
    CurrentVid.NormalizeTestFrames();
    AllVideos.Add(CurrentVid);

});
```

Disclaimer:

As already mentioned and again brought to attention by [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) the `List` `AllVideos` is not thread save. You might want to consider locking:

```
Parallel.ForEach(AllVideosFileNames, item =>
{
    MyVideo CurrentVid = new MyVideo(item, false);
    CurrentVid.PopulateAllFrames();
    CurrentVid.PopluateTestFrames();
    CurrentVid.NormalizeTestFrames();
    lock (AllVideos)
    {
        AllVideos.Add(CurrentVid);
    }    
});
```

Comment: I think I am going with this as by default it waits for the last thread to finish. Awesome fix thank you Mong

Comment: `AllVideos` being a `List<T>` is **not** thread safe; that's why you can well have problems with `AllVideos.Add(CurrentVid);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I mention it to OP in the comments below the post. I will add this information as disclaimer. Thank you for pointing out again.